# HTML5 - Drag and Drop canvas (or divs) switching both

Tags: html, canvas

I'm new with html5 and I'm trying to go through with drag and drop functionality.

This is the **scenario**: two different divs (or canvas) side by side.

What I want **to do**: drag the first div (or canvas) and drop on the second div.

Which **result** I expect: The first div content is now on the second div position and the second div content is on the first div position. Like a normal switch.

I'm pretty sure that is possible, but the only think I've done until now, was to append the first div into the second div.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/ this tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible, but the answer depends a bit on what the purpose is... If you want to learn how drag and drop works in HTML5, then write your own implementation based on the [tutorial](http://html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics) you mentioned. But if you want to build something for production within reasonable time, use a library - there are lots. Which one to use also depends on the platform you're targeting. If you're targeting mobile, you need touch support, and you need to consider multi-touch effects in your implementation - it's not just mouse clicks and drags anymore, but potentially lots of fingers simultaneously!

A nice demo using [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) can be found here: http://riagora.com/mobile/hammer/index2.html. Drag and Drop works both with mouse and touch, but you need a touch screen for zooming (by pinching) and rotation of images.

Another demo, a [puzzle](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/puzzle-demo/) using [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/), which does almost what you ask for. However, the current version, 1.9.0, is from December 23, 2010, so it doesn't seem to be actively developed anymore.